# How can i edit my mysql database?

Tags: android, mysql, json

I created my sql database and its json output looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "number": "122",
    "message": "this is message"
  }
]
```

how can i make it look like this:

```
{
  "android": [
    {
      "ver": "1.5",
      "name": "Cupcake",
      "api": "API level 3"
    }
  ]
}
```

How to get that additional tag "android"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this to get from your mysql dummy table:

```
select concat("{android:[",group_concat(concat("{number:'",122,"'"), CONCAT(",message:'",'this is message'),"'}"),"]}") as json from dual;
```

you can do this with data from any of your database tables.
for example, I've shown it with dual table

The following provides more of what you are looking for:

```
select 
concat("{android:[",
group_concat(
concat('{"number":','"122"'), 
CONCAT(',"message":','"this is message"'))
,"]}") as json from dual;
```

provides:

```
{android:[{"number":"122","message":"this is message"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to put the json object in json array by

```
jsonArr.put(subJsonObj);
```

and then

```
jsonObj.put("android", jsonArr);
```

[this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/android-json-tutorial-create-and-parse-json-data.html) may give more detailed idea

Comment: is there a way that i can achieve that in my database?? 

i want it to be like [this](http://api.learn2crack.com/android/jsonos/)

Comment: yes in that example : android is tag name for the json array and { "ver": "1.5", "name": "Cupcake", "api": "API level 3" } is an jsonobject at position 0 in that array.

you can achieve that by the code I wrote in answer above.

If you want detail example refer the guide : http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/android-json-tutorial-create-and-parse-json-data.html